# android writing images to cache not returning null on decode file

Tags: android, caching, imageview

I have the following method to write a file to cache:

```
  private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
    String filename = String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
    File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);

    // Is the bitmap in our cache?
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getPath());
    if(bitmap != null) return bitmap;

    // Nope, have to download it
    try {
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL(url).openConnection().getInputStream());
        // save bitmap to cache for later
        writeFile(bitmap, f);

        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

The problem is that is that in the line:
     if(bitmap != null) return bitmap;

This condition never returns null so my cached image is never returned. How can I see if the decode of the file in fact failed?

I know the image is being written correctly because I get the following log output for the file location:

/data/data/com.example/cache/1562036938

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hint: check the filesize before you decode.